# MongoDB: sum values in object without MapReduce

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collections of objects:

```
{
    "_id" : "01",
    "properties" : {
        "colors" : {
            "red" : 0.8891772,
            "blue" : 0.7580757,
            "green" : 0.4345628,
            "white" : 0.7373822,
            "black" : 0.93228924,
            ...
            "purple" : 0.83328924,
    }
}
```

Colors has many more keys that was shown above. Also, not every object has exactly the same keys, e.g. an object may not have properties.colors.red at all.

I need to sum the values of the color keys so that the output looks:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "key" : "Red",
    "value" : 2723.1982
}

/* 2 */
{
    "key" : "Blue",
    "value" : 972172.271
}

...
```

Where the values are the sum of the values for that color.

**EDIT**

In fact, better than just the sum for each properties.colors would be the average of the sums over the total number of documents in the original collections.

So for example:

```
{
    "_id" : "01",
    "properties" : {
        "colors" : {
            "red" : 2.0,
            "blue" : 4.0,
    }
}

{
    "_id" : "02",
    "properties" : {
        "colors" : {
            "red" : 2.0,
            "black" : 8.0,
    }
}
```

Should result in:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "key" : "red",
    "value" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "key" : "blue",
    "value" : 2.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "key" : "black",
    "value" : 4.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run two simultaneous pipeline: one that simply counts all the documents and the second one that aggregates by color. You can do that using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/). First pipeline is fairly simple: you just need [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/index.html) to get the number of elements. You can start your second aggregation with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) which will transform your nested object to an array of keys and values (`k` and `v` fields). Then you can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on that array to get single document per entry to be able to use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and `$sum`. Then you just need `$project` to reshape final result. Finally you need [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) to divide each result by the number of elements in collection. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            total: [ { $count: "value" } ],
            agg: [
                {
                    $project: {
                        colors: {
                            $objectToArray: "$properties.colors"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$colors"
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$colors.k",
                        v: { $sum: "$colors.v" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$total"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$agg"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            key: "$agg._id",
            value: { $divide: [ "$agg.v", "$total.value" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Follow-up question, @mickl: would it be possible, in the same query, to divide all the sum-values for the total of number of documents in the original collections?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, the question is what do you mean by the total number of documents: just count on collection or only those documents where particular key appears ? Or every key occurs in every document ? It'd be better to answer that in a separate question if you don't mind as it's not a best practice to modify answered question

Comment: I meant count on collection (which should be the same as considering the lack of a given key as a zero). I can edit the original question to add this follow-up.

Comment: @EdgardDerby okay please do that

Comment: The $divide part doesn't work. I suspect the reason is that $count refers to the unique keys, rather the the total count of documents in the original collection.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that, you need `$facet` to do that, check my modified answer.

Comment: This is not a query, @mickl, this is a work of art. :)